# TypeError: Can't read property 'map' of undefined when component uploads a file in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

React newb here.
When props.submitClk === true (the green light that my upload button has been clicked and a file is sent from another component's form)
, I'm trying to update state setList with a new technique object, but for now just, 'SomeObject'. I then get a "TypeError  Can't read property 'map' of undefined"  after click. I tried messing around with some conditionals, but no luck after a few hours of trying. Is this a async issue and the map is happening too soon? handleRemove works fine when I'm deleting objects. If I remove the function under the if statement, it will not throw an error on form submit. Also, the object is going to be larger, that it is why its currently nested this way. Thanks for any answers.

```
function SampleData(props) {
const [list, setList] = React.useState( [
        {
            closedguard: [
                {
                    name: "Armbar",
                    link: "",
                    x: "X",
                    id: "1",
                },
                {
                    name: "Triangle",
                    link: "",
                    x: "X",
                    id: "2",
                },
                {
                    name: "Omaplata",
                    link: "",
                    x: "X",
                    id: "3",
                },
        ] } 
    ] );  
 
    if( props.submitClk === true) {
        setList([...list, 'SomeObject'])
      }

  const handleRemove = (id) => {
    const newList = list[0].closedguard.filter(move => move.id !== id);
    setList([{ closedguard: newList }]);
};

    return (
        <div className="guard">
    
            <ul className="techUl">
                {" "}
                Closed Guard
                {list.map((pos) =>
                        pos.closedguard.map((move, id) => (
                            <li
                                key={id}
                                className="techLi"
                                                
                                >{move.name}
                                <span onClick={(id) => handleRemove(move.id)}> {move.x}</span>
                            </li>
                        ))
                    )}
            </ul>       
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: pos.closedguard is undefined.

Comment: I think to use the previous state (...list) you want to pass that as the parameter of a function in setList: `setList((prevList) => {[...list, 'SomeObject'])`

Comment: Still the same error ,but thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First without `someObject` you'll face `Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.`

Then you're updating nested object:

```
[
        {
            closedguard: [
                {
                    name: "Armbar",
                    link: "",
                    x: "X",
                    id: "1",
                },
                {
                    name: "Triangle",
                    link: "",
                    x: "X",
                    id: "2",
                },
                {
                    name: "Omaplata",
                    link: "",
                    x: "X",
                    id: "3",
                },
            ] 
        }
]
```

array of object, then object `closedguard` is inside which is an array.

So what you can do inside condition is

```
// think is the some objects
const newObject = [
      {
        name: "test1",
        link: "",
        x: "X",
        id: "5"
      },
      {
        name: "test2",
        link: "",
        x: "X",
        id: "56"
      }
    ];
    setList([{ closedguard: [...list[0].closedguard, ...newObject] }]);
```

instead of

```
setList([...list, 'SomeObject'])
```

Comment: this way you are adding elements to the `closedguard: ` array property. According to the OP code `[...list, 'SomeObject']`, this would involve creating another full parent object, not add elements to the closedguard array property. However your answer might be what the question asked...

Answer (score 1):

for updating the closeguard array of ur state `list` u can see @Nafis answer but u
should make use of useEffect hook for running sideeffects. try putting this logic coupled with @Nafis answer for updating the state -

`if( props.submitClk === true) { setList([...list, 'SomeObject']) }`

inside an useEffect hook like shown below

```
useEffect(()=>{
if( props.submitClk === true) {
    setList([...list, 'SomeObject']) }

},[list])
```

Now modify the list.map function as below, then u wont get map undefined error

```
{list.length > 0 && list.map((pos) =>
                    pos.closedguard.map((move, id) => (
                        <li
                            key={id}
                            className="techLi"
                                            
                            >{move.name}
                            <span onClick={(id) => handleRemove(move.id)}> {move.x}</span>
                        </li>
                    ))
                )}
```

let me know if it works or not

Comment: OP is not asking how to perform the ui effects and you are using my exact same fix propsal copypasted code even with the `//CHANGE HERE` comment in your answer

Comment: im really sry , i didnt mean to copy urs. i wanted to copy his code. ur was at the top so i might have misunderstood as his while copying. Thnx for pointing out

Comment: no problem, my point is that without the the fix your answer does not fix the users problem, and he is not asking for the userInterface changes update, he is already doing that succesfuly with useState, so kindly suggesting that your answer does not bring much to the table...

Comment: he is getting an error when using the map function on list array, when the file is sent from some other component this component gets mounted with true value in the props and he is trying to update the state of this components based on that true condition. So im just proposing what could be the cause of that error. Let me know if my understandings correct

Comment: the setState function with the new data will set the ui to the new updated state the same as the useEffect with the list as a dependency would. I do not see very much your point, but I am quite new to react, so can be my fault

Comment: actually react doesnt update the states right away , it updates them batchwise and is very unpredicatbale with state updates so ur component might get rendered  even though ur state i.e list here is not updated and that would lead to the undefined error. So im using useeffect so that the state update is the first thing that happens when the component mounts and then checking it like list.length >0 so that u dont get that undefine error and when react updates the state later it can be shown in the ui.

Comment: kindly have a look : https://learn.co/lessons/react-updating-state#:~:text=Setting%20state%20is%20not%20synchronous,whenever%20React%20feels%20it's%20appropriate.

Comment: I see. I was not aware of that as thought that the OPs problem was in the object that is added to the list. Yo do have a point in your anwer then. Thanks for spotting that out and for your explanation

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to update the nested object to add elemets to your `closedguard:` property array, check @Nafis answer.

What I believe is the problem is that the new objects you add do not have the `closedguard` property, so the map function cannot map that object.

If you add an object with that property it will work, for example:

```
const objToAdd = {closedguard: [
    {
    name: "newObj1",
    link: "",
    x: "X",
    id: "3",
   },
    {
      name: "newObj2",
      link: "",
      x: "X",
      id: "3",
    }] 
  }
```

If what you are doing is adding objects with another property, what you might need to map is the corresponding key, to be sure that you are getting a property out of the object, so would need to channge

`pos.closedguard.map((move, id) => (`

by:

`pos[Object.keys(pos)[0]].map((move, id) => (` for example.

So in case your object doesnt have the `closedguard`, the first property of that object would be mapped.

Posting the full return with my proposal just to leave my proposal clear:

```
return (
    <div className="guard">
      <ul className="techUl">
        {" "}
        Closed Guard
        {list.map((pos) =>
          pos[Object.keys(pos)[0]].map((move, id) => ( //CHANGE HERE
            <li
              key={id} className="techLi"         
              >{move.name}
              <span onClick={(id) => handleRemove(move.id)}> {move.x}</span>
            </li>
          ))
        )}
      </ul> 
      <button onClick={handleOnClick}>Button</button>      
  </div>
  );
```